# Broke view after migrating from .net core 2.2 to .net core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.0

I migrated an asp.net core 2.2 mvc web app (with identityserver4) to asp.net core 3.0. Now the menu navigation bar does not display (ie Change pages, external login, two factor, change password etc)

Did I do something wrong?

...

..

**ConfigureServices**

I replaced this

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

with this

```
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
```

**Configure**

I replaced this

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationLifetime lifetime)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

    }
```

with this

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

EDIT: this is the menu nav missing (after migration)
[image]

UPDATE: Issue found, razor pages under "Manage" was not loading the root "_layout"
I fixed this by adding the following to _ViewStart

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

Ok, so why did it work before? this is strange.

Comment: I don't think you are using RazorPages but Mvc. So you can remove `AddRazorPages`. And perhaps you should add `.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)`

Comment: You can also remove `endpoints.MapRazorPages();`. And check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#order) for the correct order: `UseRouting`, then `UseAuthorization`.

Comment: But the identity pages uses razorpages. IdentityServer4 takes care of Authorization

Comment: Fixed it, I know why the issue occurred but don't understand why it worked before?